# Pagespeed insights error 404, How do I fix it

Tags: pagespeed-insights

when I test my website at google PageSpeed insights, it shows the error 404 code, but my website actually can access it.

I also try to test my website at https://tools.pingdom.com/, I don't any error code.

What happened it? How can I fix it?

Thank you
Seven

get the way to fix it

Comment: Need more information like the URL of the website to be able to help.